# android material date picker is very slow

Tags: android, kotlin, date, datepicker, materialdatepicker

I am using material date picker in my app to pick two dates but when try to call this it open in many seconds also when try to select date they are also laggy and takes time.

```
fun showDatePicker(activity: Activity, fragmentManager: FragmentManager, onDateSelected: (startDate: String, endDate: String) -> Unit) {

    val constraintsBuilder = CalendarConstraints.Builder()
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1) // 1 yr ago
    val minDate = calendar.timeInMillis
    constraintsBuilder.setStart(minDate)

    calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 2) // max yr 2 years from now
    val maxDate = calendar.timeInMillis
    constraintsBuilder.setEnd(maxDate)

    val dateRange =
        MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
            .setTitleText("Select dates")
            .setSelection(Pair(null, null))
            .setCalendarConstraints(constraintsBuilder.build()) // Apply the constraints
            .build()

    val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault())

    dateRange.show(fragmentManager, "DATE_RANGE_PICKER")

    dateRange.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener { selection ->
        val startDate = simpleDateFormat.format(selection.first)
        val endDate = simpleDateFormat.format(selection.second)
Log.e("date--->>>>","not-formatted $selection.first")
        Log.e("date--->>>>","formatted $startDate")
        onDateSelected(startDate, endDate)
    }
}
```

i call it in my fragment oncreate view

```
 binding.calendar.setOnClickListener {

            showDatePicker(requireActivity(), requireActivity().supportFragmentManager) { startDate, endDate ->
                binding.selectedDate.text = "$startDate - $endDate"
                val firstDate=startDate
                val lastDate=endDate
            }
        }
```

please guide if there is something i am missing or add to make it smooth .
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I tried that too and I have the same problem, maybe need updating material library(I couldn't check on the latest version because there are other problems after updating) or use 3d the library. I don’t know how critical range picker dialog for you, you can ask the user to select first date and after second date.

Comment: Yes, I think it works well with jetpack compose not sure. Now, I have to show two dialogs  to select the first date and after the second date